# thymeleaf html element replacement

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

`<button type="button" class="dropdown" th:text="#{Lang.Select}">Please select <i class="icon icon-chevron-down"></i></button>`

how can I replace 'Please select' with backend one, and stay element `<i>` with attributes?

Answer (score 4):

You must insert an extra span, but this will be removed at generation time.
`<button type="button" class="dropdown"><span th:text="#{Lang.Select}" th:remove="tag">Please 
select<span> <i class="icon icon-chevron-down"></i></button>`

Another option is to put it to th:text, but I would prefer the first one.
`<button type="button" class="dropdown" th:text="${#{Lang.Select} + '<i class="icon icon-chevron-down"></i>'}">Please select <i class="icon icon-chevron-down"></i></button>`